# Vlookup translation error in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

Suppose I have a sheet with question numbers and different respondents. For example, in Sheet 1 we have

```
                 Q1    Q2    Q3   Q4   Q5   Q6   Q7   Q8   Q9   Q10
  Person A       1     3     1    5    2     4   1    2     1    5
  Person B       5     1     5    1    3     3   2    5     4    3
  Person C       5     1     5    1    3     3   2    5     4    3
```

On Sheet 2 we have the same setup

```
                 Q5    Q4    Q2   Q3   Q4   Q6   Q7   Q8   Q9   Q10
  Person A       
  Person B       
  Person C
```

When I type the following in on the respective sheet 2 calls:

`=vlookup(a1,Sheet1,b$1+1,0)   # return value of Person A, Q1 from sheet 1`

I get the value of Person A Q6 instead. Why?

Comment: I may just be missing something but it looks like on sheet 2 you have a _different_ setup.. `Q5    Q4    Q2   Q3   Q4   Q6   Q7   Q8   Q9   Q10` (instead of it being sequential) and I am just purely guessing that because you start at `Q5` and you call `b$1+1` that it goes to `Q6` ?

Answer (score 2):

Am I right to assume you are using Excel?

If so, the equation that I would use is:
    `=VLOOKUP($A2,Table1,MATCH(B$1,Sheet1!B1:K1)+1,FALSE)`

You can't pass a whole sheet as a parameter.  Your going to need to pass a range.  Here I named it Table1.

In the third parameter, you are adding 1 to a string, which causes problems.  Use the MATCH function to get the column number.

Comment: I used name manager to refer to the sheet. So I can just use the name.

Comment: It's probably the third parameter then.  You'll need to use the Match function.  Updated the my answer - sorry I didn't notice the the headers on the second table were out of order.

Answer (score -1):

You're using VLOOKUP wrong.

The tooltip for VLOOKUP shows that the brackets should be `("lookup_value", "table_array", "col_index_num", "[range_lookup]")`.

So it will attempt to match your first variable, the `lookup_value`, to the first instance found in the first column of your second variable, the `table_array`. It then returns the value that is in the cell displaced by the `col_index_num`-1 (ie, to return the Q1 value you would use a `col_index_num` of 2). The final part, `[range_lookup]` is optional and it allows fuzzy matching of the value you use which is normally not what you want. Unfortunately this defaults to `TRUE` (fuzzy matching) and you nearly always want to set this to `FALSE`.

In your example in the OP you attempt to add 1 to the value found in B1 which is a string. Obviously you can't add a number to a string (at least not this way).

To match to your table headers in the second table you would use:

`=VLOOKUP($A$2,Sheet1!$A$1:$K$4,RIGHT(B1,LEN(B1)-1)+1,FALSE)`

This replaces the `col_index_num` with a reference to the number in the table header (it strips the first character `Q` to do so) and then uses that to calculate what column to use.

Comment: @Damien The formula you posted in the OP doesn't work at all so I think you've made a mistake. It's not completely clear how your data is laid out but I just copied it verbatim to there with an empty A1 cell. With this layout then you would use `=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!A1:K4,2,FALSE)` to retrieve Person A's Q1 data.

Comment: Look at the second table again. The questions are in different order. So your method seems very cumbersome. I need to look for a match between the question number and respondent.

Comment: @Damien Apologies, didn't notice the second table being layed out differently for some reason. Does this new formula work? It strips the Q from the table header in table 2 and then adds 1 to it to find what column it should be reading from. It basically does what you seemed to be trying to do but strips the Q from the table header so you are no longer adding a number to a string.